# Are 127.0.0.1 and localhost considered as two different domains by browsers?

Tags: cross-domain, same-origin-policy

Are 127.0.0.1 and localhost considered as two different domains by browsers and therefore enforce cross-domain (same origin policy) restrictions?

I observed it works sometime (in case of simple web pages) and does not work with Flex based web pages.

For example:
Scenario I:
In a web page called page1.htm, you call a script as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/somejsscript.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/js/somejsscript.js"></script>
```

and you access the page as http://localhost/page1.htm

Scenario II:
You call the script as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1/js/somejsscript.js"></script>
```

and you access the page as http://localhost/page1.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Origin is defined as a scheme/host/port (port is the default value for a scheme if it doesn't exist, e.g. port 80 for http, 443 for https).  Same-origin is defined as a matching scheme/host/port.  "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" are different hosts in this case. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules

Answer (score 6):

Yes, these are different origins for web security purposes; no browsers equate them. Technically "localhost" can point anywhere, and typically (on modern systems) it points to IPv6 rather than IPv4.

Comment: And for example Firefox doesn't know how to resolve localhost with IPv6 so well and thats why he takes so long loading things. The way to resolve that is in about:config searching for ipv6 and putting the value to true. Cheers