# How can I redirect 127.0.0.1 to localhost (Java)?

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am testing Oauth2 with Twitter, according to [discussions](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5749) Twitter only allows `127.0.0.1` (it considers `localhost` invalid).

I am using Javascript to open a pop-up window and detect the callback to the urlI registered: `https://127.0.0.1:8144/Oauth2Callback`

However, my JavaScript originates from `localhost`, and according to [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256251/are-127-0-0-1-and-localhost-considered-as-two-different-domains-by-browsers) the two are considered different for the 'same origin' policy.

How can I write a redirect from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` ?

I am using Java & also tuckey-url-rewrite, so either would work.

---

My Controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/oauth2callback")
@ResponseBody
public String callback() {
    return "oauth2callback";
}
```

---

```
<rule>
    <name>Twitter Hack</name>
<condition name="host" operator="equal"> ??? 127.0.0.1 ??? /condition>
    <from>(.*)</from>
    <to type="redirect"> ??? localhost ???</to> 
</rule>
```

I want:

`twitter --(callback)--> 127 --(redirect)--> localhost`

Comment: Isn't localhost and 127.0.0.1 the same thing. You should just be able to use it.

Comment: Maybe modify your host file to point 127.0.0.1 to localhost? or vise versa. I thought they we're the same thing though.. oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
@RequestMapping("/oauth2callback")
public String callback(HttpServletRequest request) {

    /*
     * Terrible hack for testing Twitter Oauth on 'localhost'
     */
    if (request.getServerName().contains("127.0.0.1")){
        int port = request.getServerPort();
        String query = (request.getQueryString() == null) ? "" : "?" +request.getQueryString();
        String url = "redirect:https://localhost:" + port +"/oauth2callback" + query;
        return url;
    }

    return "account/oauth2callback";
}
```

`account/oauth2callback` is a simple jsp with only :

```
<body>
    <p>oauth2callback</p>
</body>
```

There's probably a better way to do this through tuckey-url-rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

check your OS's etc/host file and set the 127.0.0.1 to localhost string. It should be there by default, but sometimes it can be an issue. On windows, this is present under C:\windows\System\drivers\etc\ folder.

Its the name resolution for your OS, so you can actually put an IP to name mapping for resolving issues on your host.