# Can a Java Applicaton and a JavaScript running in a browser communicate with each other?

Tags: java, javascript

I have a JavaScript embedded in a website, running in a normal browser, and I have a Java Application running on the same machine. I am looking for a way have both communicate with each other.

I assume that creating files in the local file system from inside JavaScript running in a browser is out of question.

The only way I came up with would be to use a server that both programs can send messages to, and from which they poll for new messages.

Is there any other other way to accomplish this?

Comment: What does "on the same machine" mean here? Javascript running in browser is going to be invoked on the client. You have a Java application running on a client too?

Comment: Yes, both the Java application and the JavaScript are running on the client.

Comment: The most natural way would be for the Javascript to speak to a HTML aware server, e.g. a typical servlet running in Tomcat. The application could communicate with the servlet in any way you like, but either HTML or TCP/sockets sound logical. The servlet would then act as a pass-through in both directions.

Comment: Isn't that a usecase for nashorn (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html)?

Comment: Use case for Nashorn is to provide scripting capabilities to Java. AFAIK it has nothing to do with browser integration.

Comment: Is the Java application implied to be on the server, or on a client?

Answer (score 3):

A couple of ways I saw in practice:

- You Java Application may listen to some local port which your JS will access for instance via XHR. You'll need to mind cross-site scripting (your JS may need to be loaded from that local URL), but this is doable. The easiest would probably be to run an embedded HTTP server.
- Your Java Application may be registered as a protocoll handler in the OS. Then JS would open links registered with the application thus sending data to it.

As @PavelHoral is pointing out, [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) is a way to workaround [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: The "protocol handler" approach is very interesting idea. +1

Comment: I wonder if the browser security will allow you to connect to a server that will be running on the localhost though... Its a really interesting question and possible solution but I'd be surprised if this works the same in all browsers.

Comment: Why shouldn't you be able to connect from a browser to the local host? Like, `localhost:8080`? For XHR from JS to work, this JS must come from `localhost:8080` or see the mentioned CORS solution.

Comment: Browser is not specific enough - I'm doubting that you can connect from a web application pulled from an external webserver to something running on the localhost - with or without CORS enabled on that local server. To me it seems to be a breach of the browser sandbox to be able to do that as you'll still be accessing the local client from an externally hosted web application. I'd be interested to see some official specifications that state that browsers should allow this.

Comment: @Gimby If you get an HTML file from the web server and it contains a `<script src="http://localhost:8080/my.js"/>` then `my.js` won't break SOP when loading data per XHR from `http://localhost:8080`. CORS should also work. Why shouldn't it? Because the host is named `localhost`? Any evidence for this? Any evidence that SOP/CORS do not work with localhost?

Comment: That is indeed what I was asking for too - evidence that it is by specification -allowed- to connect to the localhost from a remotely loaded resource.

Comment: @Gimby Since `http://localhost:8080/*` and `my.js` from `<script src="http://localhost:8080/my.js"/>` are clearly same origin and the spec does not specifically prohibit `localhost`, this must work. Sorry, I can't provide an evidence that the spec *allows* `localhost` as I can't provide an evidence that the spec *allows* `google.com` or whatever else. This does not make my point less valid.

Comment: @Gimby See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262775/why-is-same-origin-policy-kicking-in-when-making-request-from-localhost-to-local) post and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256251/are-127-0-0-1-and-localhost-considered-as-two-different-domains-by-browsers) post as an evidence that SOP works for `localhost`.

Comment: @Gimby And you're right about CORS. This is indeed browser-dependent. For instance, [Chrome does not support localhost CORS](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743). But still, you can get around this with lvh.me.

Comment: @lexicore both describe localhost to localhost as far as I can tell not "any other host" to localhost which is the situation I repeatedly ask about.

Comment: @Gimby There are good indications for me to think this should work, I think I even saw this in action. But I don't want to invest more time to prove my position, sorry.

Comment: CORS [is supported in all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors). The linked issue with Chrome is for wildcard matching (also some comments seems a bit confused).

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript inside a browser can only make AJAX requests or communicate with browser plugins if they provide some additional JS interface.

**Local HTTP connection**

One option is to listen for HTTP connections in your Java application (does not have to be servlet).

You will need to handle [CORS correctly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

**Central server**

Other option is to have a central server to which both your JS and Java code will connect.

**Java applet**

Another option is to have Java applet. When running in privileged mode you can do pretty much anything (maybe you can convert your Java application to Java applet).

You will need to handle applet security here (e.g. signing applet with trusted certificate).

Comment: By the way, for the central server I saw JNLP-based solutions where web client and a rich client loaded via JNLP communicated that way. a good point.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this question for direct sockets communications from within javascript. You'll need a HTML5 browser, and likely this won't "just" work or necessarily be a good idea if you want to publish this on the WWW.

[How to Use Sockets in JavaScript\HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736382/how-to-use-sockets-in-javascript-html)