# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource laravel 5.8.8

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cors, axios, phpdesktop

I have installed barryvdh/laravel-cors as explained on the readme file in the github repository. I still have a No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource error. I am using vue, axios and laravel 5.8.8

Installed barryvdh/laravel-cors as well as added headers in my api.php file

My cors.php file looks like this

```
'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['Content-Type', 'X-Requested-With', 
                    'Origin','Authorization'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
```

In debugger tools i get the following

```
GENERAL
Request URL:http://localhost:8000/api/entriesoff
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
Allow:GET, POST, HEAD, CONNECT, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, PROPFIND, MKCOL
DAV:1
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers:x-csrf-token,x-requested-with
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:8000
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

Comment: `PROPFIND, MKCOL` are non-standard. Is there anything intercepting the response that may modify it after it's been sent?

Comment: The debugger tools are showing the response to the **preflight** OPTIONS request, but the error message says "*on the requested resource*" … so you should be looking at the response the subsequent GET request instead.

Comment: The subsequent get request is not sent.

Comment: If you are running your server using `php artisan serve` you may have to restart it. Try running `php artisan config:clear` to see if that resolves anything.

Comment: Since you didn't mention it, did you remember to add to your middleware?  `app/http/Kernel.php` this `\Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class`

Comment: You are using different origins. "127.0.0.1" and "localhost" are different origins. Try using "127.0.0.1" for all requests. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256251/are-127-0-0-1-and-localhost-considered-as-two-different-domains-by-browsers

Comment: I used php artisan serve --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8000 to set my URL to 127.0.0.1 same as origin and it works. However, I would like a permanent solution, that is, not having to run the artisan command each time. The whole point of using php desktop was to be able to run the app by launched the .exe file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I added index.php in my axios URL , for example http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.php/api/...

Answer (score -2):

you will use

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');

instead of **barryvdh/laravel-cors**

in

```
public/index.php
```

above

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

**sample:**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```